# Django add user to 'team'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want the logged in user to be able to add users to a team they have created. At the moment I have created a form which lets the user select the user and the team they want to add them to, but they can select from every team in the database rather than just those they have created. Any ideas? These are my models, view and the form i have created. Also help with what to put in my HTML file would be appreciated.

Models:

```
class UserTeams(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teamID = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    countryID = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

View:

```
def invite(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InvitePlayerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userteam = form.save(commit=False)
            userteam.save()

    else:
        form = InvitePlayerForm()
        query = UserTeams.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'teammanager/invite.html', {
        "invite": query,
        "form": form
})
```

Form:

```
class InvitePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
        model = UserTeams
        fields = ['userID','teamID']
```

HTML:

```
{% extends "teammanager/header.html" %}

{% block content %}


<html>
<body>
            <h4>Invite players to your team</h4>

    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}


</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your form like so it will do the FK filter based on the userteam object.

```
class InvitePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
        model = UserTeams
        fields = ['userID','teamID']

    def __init__(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
        super(InvitePlayerForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) 
        self.fields['teamID'].queryset = Team.objects.filter(id__in = UserTeam.objects.filter(userID = user))
```

Comment: yes, now that I realize that you dont use the invite on the template. hold on

Comment: I've applied that and it gives me the error: TypeError at /invite/
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Comment: Done, try it now

Comment: Still getting the same TypeError